# How Access Client Built In camera from Internet Browser

Tags: c#, java, android, ios, browser

I created a web application that need to access the built-in web camera of the client device to grab pictures to send to server side.
For Windows OS I'm using silverlight, and the all is working very well.
Now I need somethink like plugin or someother else in case of Android OS and iOS.
Somebody can suggest something ?
I'm programing with c#.
Best regards

Piercarlo

Comment: Using the standard HTML <form> tag, you can have access to the camera in the iOS 6 beta.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make an active X control

see more info on active x controls here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Or you would use a flash application in yr page for other browsers besides IE

Comment: Can you link some examples about flash ?

Comment: here is a start http://www.adobe.com/designcenter-archive/tutorials/fla8at_cameraobj/